# difference between use of call,bind,apply and object prototyping?

Tags: javascript

I have tried so much to understand call/bind/apply but still am so much confused to find why we use call/bind/apply in javascript and is it the same as object prototyping?

Comment: Nothing in common with object prototyping. `call`/`bind`/`apply` are only different ways to execute a function and supply it with context and parameters.

Comment: I read an article where the words are: "it allows us to call a function with a given this context and arguments. They let us call a function and have access to the properties of another function or object. We can borrow methods of one object’s prototype and use it to another" Now I am confused that we do the same in object prototyping that we create a Constructor function with "this" and we create different objects with that , with different "this" references.

Comment: The prototype is not directly related. A prototype just defines what methods a type of object would have. And "methods" in JS are functions which execute with the context set to the instance you're calling them from: `foo.someMethod()` and `bar.someMethod()` can share the code for `someMethod()` but the context (the `this` keyword) would be different. But you can also have a proper function (not a method) that uses `this` within its body and execute it against different instances like `someFunction.call(foo)` and `someFunction.call(bar)`.

Comment: So, simply put `call`/`apply`/`bind` are not directly related to prototype inheritance, but prototype inheritance relies on the [`this` keyword](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3127429/how-does-the-this-keyword-work), thus you can "borrow" a method from one instance to execute against another `cat.meow.call(dog)` is valid way to transiently call `dog.meow()` without `dog` actually having this method.

Comment: ok, I got the point. Thank you